# Explain schematic for one-shot trigger

Tags: switches, schematics, latch, trigger, latching

Can you please help to explain following schematic:

[image: One-shot trigger circuit]

- How does this circuit work?
- What is the purpose of the diode and the capacitor?

Comment: Does the circuit work? The diode is for clamping the gate of the MOSFET on the higher side to VBATT + diode VF.

Comment: Circuit should work, as far I saw on YT video. Diode is not needed if it is for clamping to high side, it can be done over resistor. As far I understand when reset pin is switched to active ground, capacitor will star slowly charging over R10 resistor which allows MOSFET to be open until threshold is reached. However, when RESET is switched back to HIGH side, capacitor will discharge via diode. I don't know if actually the case.

Comment: Yes, the diode is helping discharge the capacitor when RESET goes HIGH. This is what I meant by clamping. You need the diode.

Comment: My doubt is regarding the case when the Reed switch is off. There will be no supply for the IC. So, we cannot predict the value of RESET. Assume it settles to 0V, now, if the Reed switch turns ON, there will be no high to low transition on RESET because it is already low. So, it will not turn ON Q3. To turn ON Q3, you need a high to low transition on RESET

Comment: Not sure I understand you comment. Are You imply that when VDD pin is HIGH, RESET pin will be LOW: " ...if the Reed switch turns ON, there will be no high to low transition on RESET because it is already low." This is not correct assumption as far I understand datasheet of TPS3839G33.